# File listing shows attributes in some folders but not in others

Tags: php

I'm having trouble trying to get attributes from files in my list. The code is:

```
if ($this->dir = opendir($caminho))
{
    $this->itens = array();
    $this->itensTotal = 0;
    $tipos = array("dir" => 0, "file" => 1);

    while ($item = readdir($this->dir))
    {
        if (!in_array($item, $this->skip))
        {
            $t = filetype($item);
            $this->itens[$tipos[$t] . $item] = array("nome" => $item,
                                                     "size" => filesize($item),
                                                     "tipo" => $t,
                                                     "perm" => fileperms($item));

            $this->itensTotal++;
        }
    }
}
```

Seeing that my script is 'file.php' and is in the folder 'www'. When it reads it's own folder (www) it works ok and lists all files and directoryies with their attributes. But when it tryies to read eg.: */www/folder/* the function `filetype()`, `filesize()` an `fileperms()` doesn't works! I get these warnings for all itens in the directory:

> Warning: filetype() [function.filetype]: Lstat failed for bkp in
>   D:\UniformServer\UniServer\www\files.php on line 174
>
> Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for bkp in
>   D:\UniformServer\UniServer\www\files.php on line 176
>
> Warning: fileperms() [function.fileperms]: stat failed for bkp in
>   D:\UniformServer\UniServer\www\files.php on line 178

It's opens the folder, read it's contents but these functions doesn't woks =s

Notes:

- As you can see I'm running it on Windows
- `$caminho` has valids paths

Please, any help will be welcome cause google doesn't helped.

Comment: You say `/www/folder`, but you're on Windows, which uses `\ ` for paths, not `/`. Which are you using?

Comment: Well, I'm using `/` cause `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` returns me `D:/UniformServer/UniServer/www/`. I didn't realize that on the warning it's uses `\\`

Comment: php can translate the slashes, that's not a worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file operations use the real directory names on the system, not the relative path of the website,  and `"/www/folder"` probably doesn't exist then.  From your comment, you would need either: `"D:/UniformServer/UniServer/www/folder"` or use a relative path from the php script.

Answer (score 0):

I think `$item` only contain the [basename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basename) of the file. You should probably prepend the directory path to it, like this: `filetype(this->dir . $item)`.

Comment: You both right, but `$this->dir` handles the resource, `$caminho` has the path.